# ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oracle11g, odp.net

I'm trying to connect my local Oracle 11g database using server explorer in Visual Studio 2010. I tried to setup everything as per instruction, but I'm still getting an ORA-12504 error.

Here is the error:

[image]

Here is my tnsnames.ora contents:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\rsahi\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.


VENUS =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = SPRPRG020)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = VENUS)
    )
  )

LISTENER_VENUS =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = SPRPRG020)(PORT = 1521))
```

listener.ora file contents,

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\rsahi\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = SPRPRG020)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\app\rsahi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced the same problem when I was trying to create LinkedServer with Oracle 11g. My oracle instance name was: **PC-2.my.xgen** and my listener name was "**NB**". The last parameter of first statement is actually the concatenation of Oracle server instance and listener name.

So I have write down the following statements in SQL server.

```
--add a linked server into SQL server
--last parameter contains OracleInstance / Listener Name of desired database
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver   'OracleLinkedServer4', 'Oracle',   'MSDAORA', 'PC-2.my.xgen/nb'

--add login information into linked server
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'OracleLinkedServer4', false,  Null, 'system',  '123456'
```

In Oracle database "NB" I have a table named : CRD_CIL_NOTIFICATION_TYPE. So I have written down the following statement to get the records.

```
select * from OracleLinkedServer4..SYSTEM.CRD_CIL_NOTIFICATION_TYPE
```

Answer (score 20):

Try this, in Visual Studio's Server Explorer Data Connection panel:

`Data source name: SPRPRG020/VENUS`

i.e. the Data source name format is SERVER_NAME_OR_IP/DATABASE_NAME

Comment: Using SSIS, this tip does describe the format that is needed in the Data Source field on the "Choose a Data Source" step in the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard.

Comment: This worked for me!!!  I was trying to connect to an Oracle DB to build an SSRS report. I had already successfully added the database in my VS Server Explorer...so I figured I was very close. But I couldn't get the connection made as an actual SSRS data source.... until I tried what @Rena Luna suggested.  I looked at the connection string for my existing Server Explorer connection to the Oracle DB and noticed it had IP:port/<name>  Not sure what the <name> part refers to as I'm not an Oracle guy. Put I put this in as the connection string (Oracle Db connection type) in my SSRS data source!!

Answer (score 3):

In the "Connection Properties" -> "Advanced" set in the "Data Source" field the information in format HOST/SERVICE_NAME. E.g. 127.0.0.1/TEST

Answer (score 1):

Without having much knowledge in connecting ODP.NET with an Oracle DB, I suggest you start using SERVICE_NAME (e.g: VENUS) in your connection parameters.

Oracle states that:

*From 11g onwards, the feature of using the hostname provided in the /etc/hosts file, as the alias / service name has been changed.  As a result, the user will have to provide the service name while connecting OR configure the target listener with a default service name.*

One way to bypass the SERVICE_NAME client side requirement is to force the Listener always sending you on the same SERVICE by telling it to do so in the tnsnames.ora

```
DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER =  VENUS
```

But I do not suggest you do that as it's quite restricting.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Connection Properties" -> "Advanced" set in the "Data Source" field the information in format HOST:PORT/SERVICE_NAME. E.g. 10.xxx.xxx.xxx:1521/SIDNAME