# Connecting to Oracle Database using Sql Server Integration Services

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, ssis

I have a requirement to get the data from Oracle database to Sql Database using the SSIS.

I am using sql Server 2012 Standard Edition 64 bit and oracle is 11g.

I tried downloading the oracle drivers(64-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC)) to install in Sql server with will allow me to connect to Oracle db but not able to achieve the same.

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have had to do this on many occasions, unfortunately the Oracle website is not particularly helpful when trying to determine what you need.

You need to download a copy of 
"ODTwithODAC1120320_32bit.exe" which can be found at:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html

The 64-bit version is of no use, the 32 bit drivers will work just fine. Install this on your development machine and on the SQL Server box if you want to run the packages from the agent.

You can then choose the provider ".Net Providers\OracleCLient Data Provider".
The connection string will look some like this (I think 1521 is the default Oracle port):

(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xxxxx)))

Comment: Thanks for the response after installing the drivers do we need to do any thing on configuration?

Comment: ".Net Providers\OracleCLient Data Provider". am not clear on these,if am not wrong these we have to use in creating the package connection right ?

Comment: No configuration of the drivers is necessary. All you do is setup your connection when you are inside your package. You can add connections in your connection manager, right-click and choose "new ado.net connection" then you click "new.." where you can setup your new connection to Oracle

Comment: can you plesae tell me which product need to install either Oracle Data access componets for oracle client or server??

Comment: Just click on the link above and download the first item, ODAC 11.2 Release 5 and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (11.2.0.3.20), this is all you need to install. Install this on your machine and on the SQL server box. It will install all the necessary components for connecting to oracle via SSIS. Once it is done you can go into sql server data tools (or BIDS if using 2008) and the provider will be there.

Comment: yeah i have downloaded the setup from the link given by you but when i  click on the setup it is asking for me to select the product like oracle Data Access componetns for Oracle Client 11.2.0.3.20 r Oracle server 11.2.0.3.20

Comment: Oh, I see. Oracle Client.

Comment: Thanks,so after installing these driver directly i can go to BIDS to create a package to connect to oracle database correct?

Comment: After selecting Ado.Net as a connection manager it is asking for me the provider,which provider i have to use"

Comment: drop down is giving me .Net provider and .Net providers for Oledb??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34981/discussion-between-twoleggedhorse-and-user2315732)

Comment: Sorry chat is not allowed to me.

Comment: The provider you want is ".Net Providers\OracleClient Data Provider".

Comment: yeah i selected the same but it states am Error Message saying that "Test Connection failed because of an Error Initializing provider.ORA-12504:TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_Da

Comment: Make sure the connection string has service name: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xxxxx))) obviously change the xxxx for the actual service name, or you can use SID instead. And change the IP address to be that of the oracle server.

Comment: where i will get these connection string ??

Comment: Click on the All tab and it goes in the data source box at the bottom

Comment: Yes in Data Source i have given the server Name

Comment: In DataSource i have given as XXX(Server Name) do i need to give as mentioned by you??

Comment: I am not finding where to mention the IP address aswell

Comment: You need to put the following in data source, change OracleIPAddress to the actual IP and OracleSID to the SID: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=OracleIPAddress)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=OracleSID)))

Comment: i have given the OracleIDAdress as XXX and Service_Name as ServerNameofOracle still the same error

Comment: For SID see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43866/how-sid-is-different-from-service-name-in-oracle-tnsnames-ora

Comment: For IP see http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/identifying-host-names-and-addresses.php

Comment: i have provided the details same like the links still the same error

Comment: You will have to ask your oracle database admin for the connection string, you will also have to verify that you can connect to the oracle box remotely and that the ports are correct. You have all the correct tools installed but I can't get you the connection string as I don't have access to your systems.

Comment: Thanks buddy now i resolved the issue after changing the DataSource but is there a way to connect to oracle using the ODBC source.

Comment: Ask another question as this is becoming a really long comments section.

Comment: When the connection details exceed 128 characters, the following cannot be used (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=OracleIPAddress)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_D‌​ATA=(SERVICE_NAME=OracleSID))) , Instead when you put ServeriP/DBName, it works fine. Found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825552/ora-12504-tnslistener-was-not-given-the-service-name-in-connect-data

Answer (score 5):

You should try and use the SSIS Connectors for Oracle (produced by Attunity). They are freely downloadable from Microsoft [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=29284). The SSIS Connectors provide optimal performance when selecting data from an Oracle db. In addition you need to setup the tnsnames.ora file with the correct connection configuration.

Comment: If you are using SSIS 2012 and SQL Server 2012 use this link to download the SSIS connectors: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29283

Comment: SSIS Connectors for Oracle (produced by Attunity) only work for **Enterprise or Developer** Editions of SQL Server *not* Standard. See [MS System Requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44582)

Comment: Why use the Connectors over the Oracle tools or drivers?