# SQL Server Configuration not able to retrieve password from the table

Tags: sql, oracle, ssis, ssis-2008

I have SSIS package which i connecting to a oracle server and truncate a table. If I configure the package using XML configuration my package is succeeding. I want to utilize SQL server configurations for my package. If I set that up, I'm not able to make a connection to oracle server.

Error Message::
"ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied"

I think the issue is with the table where the configuartion values are stored When the package is trying to retreive password. Password fields are showing as asterisks. Any parameter or options I need to specify in this case? Please help!

Comment: Can your try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096409/connecting-to-oracle-database-using-sql-server-integration-services)

Comment: @Dhnesh I dont have any issue with Oracle connectivity. The issue is with using SQL server Configuration table

Comment: --Sql Authentication

Data Source= <ServerName>;User ID=<username>; Password= <password>; Initial Catalog=<DBName>; Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Persist Security Info=True;

--Windows Authentication

Data Source= <ServerName>; Initial Catalog=<DBName>; Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;

Comment: try above one to connecting sql server

Comment: Have a look at the package protection level, if you are inside a strong protected network you could look to use "Don't Save Sensitive" - this may help?