# Error trying to connect to Oracle DB with SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008, oracle11g, ssis

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle database using SSIS, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. Oracle client and 
networking components were not found. These components are supplied by Oracle 
Corporation and are part of the Oracle Version 7.3.3 or later client software installation.
Provider is unable to function until these components are installed.
```

A search returned [this link](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jorg_klein/archive/2011/06/09/ssis-connect-to-oracle-on-a-64-bit-machine.aspx) and downloaded the zip files in the [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html). But I have no idea what to do with the contents of these zip files.

Another link also mentions to download [Microsoft Connector for Oracle by Attunity](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29284), but again, I don't know what to do with them.

Any help is appreciated.

I'm using Sql Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008, and VS2008. I don't exactly what version of Oracle the DB's in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting to Oracle Database using Sql Server Integration Services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096409/connecting-to-oracle-database-using-sql-server-integration-services)

Comment: More importantly, have you researched the Oracle method of database access? The error clearly states that your client does not recognize they exist. Are they installed? Please refer to [Integration Services Connections - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140203.aspx) check under the section titled `Connection Managers Available for Download`