# How to connect Sql server using SSIS package with Oracle database to different machine?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle11g, ssis, ssis-2012

I am new to Oracle database. I am trying to connect the SQL server using SSIS package to Oracle database which is present in different machine.

There is default Oracle provider in SSIS but it's not connecting to the database. I use db visualizer for creating Oracle database in the server machine.

Comment: You need to install the Oracle _client_ on the machine running SSIS in order to connect to Oracle. Here's some downloads although I'm not 100% certain which one you need http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html. PS in future please explain the issue don't just say "it's not connecting" - you need to post the error

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the *"Oracle Data Access Components"* or *"Oracle Client"* on your machine.

There are a lot of step-by-step article on how to connect to Oracle using SSIS:

- [Steps To Connect SSIS to Oracle](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crminogic/archive/2016/12/26/steps-to-connect-ssis-to-oracle)
- [Connecting to Oracle Database using Sql Server Integration Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096409/connecting-to-oracle-database-using-sql-server-integration-services)
- [Connecting to Oracle 11g on 64-bit (x64) machine SSIS 2012](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f2e365f0-45cc-43f0-be70-9358701387a2/connecting-to-oracle-11g-on-64bit-x64-machine-ssis-2012?forum=sqlintegrationservices)
- [SSIS to Oracle Connection](https://ayadshammout.com/2015/02/06/ssis-to-oracle-connection/)

**Oracle ODAC download link**

- [32-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html)
- [64-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html)