# linked server cannot initialize the data source object of Oledb.oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle11g, linked-server, oraoledb

i had linked server from sql server to oracle. it worked fine. but today i opened sql server Management Studio in windows authentication and tried to open linked server,it gave me error: cannot initialize the data source object of Oledb.oracle for linked server.

i tried to switch on and off allow in process option. but didnt worked either.

could you help me on this issue?

Comment: Check your tnsnames.ora file - Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825552/ora-12504-tnslistener-was-not-given-the-service-name-in-connect-data

Comment: i restarted the server i use,and it worked.